# Not able to use ViewContainerRef in angular4

Tags: javascript, angular

suppose i have a component like this

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  template: `
<div> 
  <div class='parent' #parent></div>
  <div class='child' #child></div>
</div>
  `
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, AfterContentInit {
  @ViewChild('parent', { read: ViewContainerRef }) parent: ViewContainerRef;
  @ViewChild('child', { read: TemplateRef }) child: TemplateRef<any>;
  constructor(private container: ViewContainerRef) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }    

}
```

I wanted to place the child div inside the parent div, but when i used like this, still i am not able to achieve it

```
 ngAfterContentInit() {
        this.parent.createEmbeddedView(this.child)
      }
```

Comment: `template: 
<div> 
  <div class='parent' #parent><div class='child' #child></div></div>
</div>` ?

Comment: Why do you need to do this? What are you specifically trying to achieve? It seems like maybe you want to create a separate component for the child div.

Comment: no, i want to place the child div inside the parent div programatically, ie. using angular method, something like using viewContainerRef and TemplateRef

Comment: @ExplosionPills i want to learn how to use ViewContainerRef, while using the ViewContainerRef, i found a method called createEmbeddedView, so i want to know how to use it

Comment: Have you tried doing this in the `ngAfterViewChecked()`?